# Как десериализовать многомерный массив из строки?

Tags: массивы, java, unserialize

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Дано:

Строка вида:

```
{{1,2,3},{10,20,30},{1234,2435,567,8679,78678}}
```

Поле класса вида:

```
public static int[][] INT_2_ARRAY = {};
```

И метод десериализации, в который подается эта строка и ссылка на тип переменной:

```
public static Object deserialize(String str, Class<?> clazz){}
```

Массив может быть любой мерности и любого основного типа (short, int, double и прочие, включая боксовые версии).

Нужно придумать способ создать и заполнить массив из строки.

Единственное, что приходит на ум - парсить строку в лист листов (уже смешно), и дальше преобразовывать в массив рекурсивно. Но мне этот способ кажется немного топорным, хотелось бы что-то более красивое.

Есть еще мысль кастовать вложенные массивы объектов к нужному классу, но не получилось.
Хотя это и странно, ведь N-мерный массив - это всего лишь массив ссылок на (N-1)-мерные массивы. Пробовал воссоздать структуру, и скастовать, но ни чего не вышло.

Еще один вопрос - как из ссылки на класс массива можно получить тип этого мисстива? В данном случае int. Не прибегая к парсингу .getCanonicalName().

Буду благодарен за любые подсказки и вообще отклики.

Comment: Так-с. Открыл для себя Array.newInstance(), но не могу понять, как можно получить ссылку на класс по названию, в том числе для простых типов (int, float). Боксовые типы по имени рефлексией берутся хорошо, а вот мелюзга эта - ни в какую.

Comment: > как из ссылки на класс массива можно получить тип этого мисстива

`arrayClass.getComponentType();`

Comment: Это здорово, но для int[][][] возвращает ссыль на int[][]. Массив может быть многомерным, и как понять в цикле, что это уже базовый тип массива? Парсить скобки?

Comment: А в чём сложность-то?

    Class<?> getArrayElementClass(Class<?> arrayClass) {
     Class<?> elementClass = arrayClass;
     while (elementClass.isArray()) {
      elementClass = elementClass.getComponentType();
     }
     return elementClass;
    }

Comment: Да, уже сам к этому ответу пришел... Поспешил с комментарием.
Спасибо, буду думать дальше над парсом и заполнением.